# Connecting with PuTTY to Amazon EC2 Windows instance running freeSSHd

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, putty

I could connect to EC2 Linux instance using PuTTY, but I need to connect it to Amazon EC2 Windows instance.

I installed freeSSHd server on EC2 Windows instance to support SSH client request on port 22. SSH server is running on port 22.

When I tried to connect, it is asking for a password. After trying with some of the available passwords, it is rejecting the connection. I have tried with usernames ec2-user, root & administrator.

- The link that gone through for the putty configuration:
  ["Server Refused our key" after launching instance from private EBS AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614254/server-refused-our-key-after-launching-instance-from-private-ebs-ami/14219815#14219815)
- [Connect ssh(putty) to ec2 instance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lA25bTzaHH4)

Is it possible to connect to the Amazon EC2 windows instance using PuTTY?

Comment: There's no SSH server in Windows by default. Though, if you are getting prompted for password, you must have installed SSH server. Did you?

Comment: Installed freeSSHd server on ec2 windows instance to support ssh client request on port 22. SSH server is running on port 22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, freeSSHd is unreliable and obsolete server. I suggest you use a different one.

Actually, [Microsoft now provides a beta version of OpenSSH port for Windows](https://serverfault.com/q/648855/168875).

---

Anyway, configure the accounts in freeSSHd settings. And then use the configured credentials in PuTTY.