# Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts - Accidentally removed all files from my .ssh folder

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

Noob here. I removed all the files from my `/Users/fakename/.shh` folder. The result is that now I can't git clone a repository from beanstalk. When I try I get the error `Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts Permission denied (public key)`. I am also having problems doing a SSH login into an EC2 instance on Amazon Web Services.

What would be the steps to get things back to normal?

**EDIT 1**

I am currently trying to generate a new rsa key pair, but getting the following:

```
open /Users/fake-name/.ssh/id_rsa failed: Permission denied.
Saving the key failed: /Users/fake-name/.ssh/id_rsa.
```

Comment: Have you tried a `touch known_hosts` and chmod 644 on the new file inside the .ssh directory?  Perhaps it can't create the file on its own.

Comment: asafreedman Yes, I have done exactly that. It didn't work. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: if you dont have backup, you need to generate a new key pair

Answer (score 2):

You can't recover the already lost keys.

Change the ownership of the ~/.ssh directory to your user

```
sudo chown fakename:fakename .ssh
```

and generate a new pair of rsa keys using `ssh-keygen`

Regarding recovering your ec2 instance, check out the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881469/change-key-pair-for-ec2-instance) if your Users folders is EBS backed, else if you are the only user, you are [screwed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901856/ec2-key-pair-change)